# My SQL version error for generate random number

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

In my local computer mysql working following SP without syntax error.

```js
REATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createAccountNumber`(IN origin_type_id INT,IN membership_type_id INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE random_number,account_number Varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL;

SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (9999999-1000000+1)+1000000) INTO random_number
WHERE 'number' NOT IN (SELECT number FROM random_numbers)
LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO random_numbers VALUES(random_number);
 
 SET @acc = CONCAT('100000',(select cast(origin_type_id as nchar)), (select cast(membership_type_id as nchar)), (select cast(random_number as nchar)));
 SET @x= luhn_sum(@acc);

SET account_number = CONCAT(@acc,@x);

 SELECT account_number;

END
```

But in the server it gives following error

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
>   ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'number' NOT IN (SELECT number FROM random_numbers)
>   LIMIT 1;

My local computer mysql version is

> mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for Win64 on x86_64

In my server mysql Version is

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41, for Linux

If there is any alternative please suggest me.

Comment: Use `WHERE number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM random_numbers)` ... remove the single quotes around the field `number`.

Comment: That is not working because there is no column called number.@Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Well if `number` does not exist, and `'number'` makes no sense, then what are you trying to do in your code?

Comment: Please add a full description of what your stored proc is trying to do.